# Can URW Garamond N°8 be used in a printed book?

Tags: legal, font-licensing

Is it possible to use the URW Garamond N°8 in a printed book (for sale)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Aladdin Public License](http://www.artifex.com/downloads/doc/Public.htm) under which URW released Garamond No. 8 specifies how it can and cannot be distributed and copied, not what it can be used to create. You can create a printed work using it and sell the work (that's what fonts are for, after all), but you specifically can't sell a copy of the font software itself.

Comment: But then, what are the licenses that give you a number of user licenses? Does it mean they can only be installed on a number of machines, but can still be used to create sold material?

Comment: Raphink - exactly.

Comment: So ANY font can be used to create sold printed books, but not to use in computer programs for example, right?

Comment: There is no universal rule for this. Some licenses are very liberal, some are very restrictive. Typical variables to look for: use in logos, use on retail products (like t-shirts), use in software, use as embedded fonts in digital documents (PDF), use as web fonts, allowed to share one copy with printer, allowed to modify letterforms for personal use, use for film titles